# I want to write a code using d3js to fetch data from csv and update it using modal popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, d3.js, modal-dialog

Here is csv file:

`Surname,Name,Phone,eMail
Stupich,Andrew,719-817-2323,jhsdj@gmail.com
Miles,Wally,719-415-7177,sjdhf@gmail.com
McLaren,Brenda,719-817-1096,sdjfhj@gmail.com`

I want to write a code using d3js, to fetch  some columns of data from a csv file on the html page & if I double click a particular cell except the headers, I should get a modal popup window with some more details of that cell record.

And if I edit some values in that modal popup, it should get updated and reflected back into the cell  of table on the page and also in the csv file from where we fetched the data. And please use d3js code mostly.

Comment: i guess d3 js is mostly used to build svg components .. why you have to use d3js only ??

Comment: No not only d3js but also in a combination with jquery html.........

Comment: can u make this code happen..........??

Comment: This sounds like a whole project. I'm not sure if StackOverflow will make a whole solution for you... We can certainly look at some code, and help from there.